# Dependency mechanism on build system

Tags: build, architecture, dependencies, system

The dependency mechanism on build systems of today check the file timestamps or checksums for changes. Is it possible to create a build system that can do that by hooking the CreateProcess(), OpenProcess(), CreateFile(), CloseHandle(), and WriteFile() functions of kernel32.dll?

Comment: What does this have to do with functional-programming?

Comment: I wouldn't go near a build system that's based on hooking system functions. You can monitor the file system for changes in official, documented ways. Another matter is that such a system would be inherently unportable.

Comment: Think about it, create an continuous build tool which will automatically build your project if it detects a change in a file, keeping your project up-to-date

Comment: I considered adding this feature to my build system ( http://iwant.sourceforge.net ) as a linux fuse filesystem. So I would mount my sources as a file system that tracks modifications. But, as must be done before any optimizations, I did some performance measuring, and: YAGNI! Checking timestamps of sources is so fast there is no need for optimization.